# Github API ignoring sort and direction on PR comments API call?

Tags: github, github-api

I want to know if the Github API has an issue here or if I am using it wrong.

Basically, to list comments posted on a PR, GitHub offers the [Issues API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments). Basically, this allows you to enter a URL param to determine the direction and the sorting criteria of the response: direction can be `asc` or `desc`, and sort can be `updated` or `created`.

I'd intuitively expect these to allow me to sort the comments ascendingly or descendingly by update timestamp.

The problem is that none of them makes a difference:

https://api.github.com/repos/nullset2/smbdxfortunes/issues/3/comments?sort=updated&direction=desc

https://api.github.com/repos/nullset2/smbdxfortunes/issues/3/comments?sort=updated&direction=asc

Both return the same result.

I am aware that the GH API docs say:

```
. . .
created means when the repository was starred. updated means when the repository was last pushed to.
. . .
```

So is this the case? If I cannot get a sorted response from the API I'll just sort them on the back-end but I wanted to see if I could get the desired result from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that my request library skipped query parameters.

Comment: I see. For context btw, I was not using any libraries when I ran into this.

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos Does sorting work for you now?

Comment: unfortunately no, the two links above still produce the same results.